# Data > JSON - Swift3 - Convert & Parse

Tags: ios, json, parsing, swift3

having one heck of a time handling the response I get from my API within a Swift3 app I'm building.

In the below screenshot, I am receiving Data from an httprequest using URLSession.shared, and passing it through to the handleSuccess method ... I am having issues simply converting to a JSON obj and accessing any of the key/values ...

[image: trying to parse]

...

```
func handleSuccess(jsonResponse: Data)
{
    NSLog("Handle Success: \(jsonResponse)")

    do
    {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonResponse, options: .allowFragments)
        NSLog("json: \(json)")

        // I simply want to:
        let firstName = json["firstName"]
```

Comment: where you are getting the error. 
Try type casting this as nsdictionary and then get json.object(forKey: "firstName") as! String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to parse your json into a dictionary first :

```
var firstName = ""
if let dict = json as? [String : AnyObject] {
  firstName = dict["firstName"] as! String
}

...

UserManager.sharedInstance.firstName = firstName
```

Comment: `let firstName = dict["firstName"] as! String`

Comment: Yuss!!! Thanks everyone :) ... var firstName = "" ... 
            if let dict = json as? [String : AnyObject] {
                firstName = dict["firstName"] as! String
            }